# Does CoffeeScript have simplified "and", "or" operators?

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript, control-flow, simplify, simplification

Could it be simplified in CoffeeScript:

```
redisSETNXReply.toString() == '1' or redisSETNXReply.toString() =='0'
```

to something like:

```
redisSETNXReply.toString() == '1' or '0'
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
redisSETNXReply.toString() in ['1', '0']
```